# How to reuse bookmarks contextmenu. (Contextmenu commands not issued.)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a Firefox addon that creates several buttons with dropdowns. Each dropdown contains several menu items representing bookmarks. 
Almost identical to bookmark folders or tags on the bookmarks toolbar (after having dragged them there) which also have dropdowns with bookmark menu items.

I would like to **reuse bookmarks contextmenu** already existing on those latter dropdown menu-items. 
I have found this way of doing it partly, but I'l stuck (see below how):

```
var mi = doc.createElementNS(XUL_NS,'menuitem');
mi.setAttribute('class',        'menuitem-iconic bookmark-item menuitem-with-favicon');
mi.setAttribute('scheme',       'http');
//this gets the existing contextmenu all right
mi.setAttribute("context",      "placesContext");
//this.pp = my own dropdown menupopup, 
this.pp.appendChild(mi);
```

Resulting contextmenu screenshot:
[image: contextmenu screenshot]

**First (minor) problem:**
Everything is grayed out until I first right-click on one of the latter dropdown items before right-clicking my own.

**Second (major) problem:** 
When hitting a command/menu-item of the placesContext menu, the commands (e.g. "Open" or "Open in new tab") are not done. Nothing happens.  Is there some attributes that my menu-item misses so that the "placesCmd_open" ignores it or do I really have to override the existing event listeners of placesContext or even different?!

Comment: Are the latter drop down menu items different from your own? How are you creating that drop down? Do you have any code I can use to resimulate your dropdowns?

Comment: No, it's the firefox built-in contextmenu for bookmarks, and this is the whole problem. I can show it, but not double use it. That is actually my problem. The code so far is just that (5th) one line  in my question description with "placesContext" in it.

Comment: Can you package the addon and share. I feel this is something you just have to hack on to get right.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ortomala, I'm nut sure why my question does not comply to a mcve.  Feel free to specify and I'll try to correct.